# Filtered foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, foreign-key, subtypes

I have two tables:

- Contact (ID, Type);
- Address (ID).

Is it possible to define a foreign key from Address (ID,'A') to Contact (ID,Type)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you want to implement a supertype/subtype relationship between the two tables (an `Address` is a `Contact`), you can, with a column having a fixed value of `'A'` and use it for the foreign key:

```
CREATE TABLE Contact
  ( ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    Type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, Type)
  ) ;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Address
  ( ID INT NOT NULL,
    Type  VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A',
    CHECK (Type = 'A'),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, Type),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID, Type)
      REFERENCES Contact (ID, Type)
  ) ;
```

---

Alternatively we could declare `Type` in Address as a persisted computed column (the check constraint would not be needed then):
`Type AS CAST('A' AS varchar(10)) PERSISTED`

```
CREATE TABLE Address
  ( ID INT NOT NULL,
    Type AS CAST('A' AS varchar(10)) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID, Type),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID, Type)
      REFERENCES Contact (ID, Type)
  ) ;
```

Comment: I ended up adding a restricted type column to the child table.

Comment: It’s sucks that we can’t out literals in the FK definition, like `FOREIGN KEY FK_Contacts ( Id, ‘A’ ) REFERENCES Contacts ( Id, Type )`

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key needs to reference a primary key or unique constraint.

Looking at your tables I assume you want Contacts to have an ID that exists in Address? If so, providing you have a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` constraint on the ID column in Address then...

```
ALTER TABLE Contacts WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Contacts_Address] FOREIGN KEY(ID)
REFERENCES Address (ID)
```

If you are saying a Contact **must** have an address that has a type 'A' then you will need to use an `INSTEAD OF` trigger or a stored procedure that runs on a schedule to list any Contacts that don't have Address type 'A'.